# Starting and Stopping SAS Server 9.2 in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, sas

I'm new to SAS server also. So if my question is a little childish, please don't mind.

I want to know how to start / stop SAS ver9.2 Server on a Unix Platform.???

Searched Google but I didn't find anything in past two or three hours.

This only information i've presently. If you want more information to answer, tell me..

Answer (score 2):

On each SAS server machine in your environment run *sas.servers start* and *sas.servers stop*.  Where you find these scripts will depend on where the SAS deployment configuration directory tree was installed. In my installation it is */opt/ebiedieg/Lev1/sas.servers* for example.

If you only have a single machine installation then you only have 1 script to run.  If you have a multi-machine installation then you should start/stop the SAS services in the correct order, running sas.server on each machine in turn.  This would be something like 1) SAS Metadata Tier 2) SAS Compute Tier 3) SAS Mid Tier to start and the reverse to stop.

The sas.servers script does not start/stop any web application server that you have (e.g. JBoss, WebLogic, WebSphere), so you will need to use an appropriate script/command depending on which one you have (if any).

You'll find the documentation for this in the SAS 9.2 Intelligence Platform: System Administration Guide, Second Edition on the [Using the sas.servers Script on UNIX or z/OS to Start or Stop All Servers](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/bisag/64088/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003280355.htm) page.